# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ses_identities' (ses_email.py)

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, smtp, amazon-ses

Iam trying to run the sample python script given in docs for sending a mail using aws SES.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/code-samples/latest/catalog/python-ses-ses_email.py.html

But when i run the script, i face the error :

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ses_identities'
```

Note: I have installed boto3

Answer (score 0):

You have to also download [ses_identities.py](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/code-samples/latest/catalog/python-ses-ses_identities.py.html) and any other file provided in the link in your question.